# Python calculating average from .txt file with Strings and numbers

Tags: python, string, parsing, numbers, average

I am new to python and need some help with how to code this.

### I have a text file that i need to do some calculations to. I need to print out `URL1 --> average(number+number+number )` `URL2 --> average` and etc

input text file:

URL1

Number

Number

Number

URL2

Number

Number

Number

URL3

Number

Number

Number

---

What i want is

Url1 numberaverage

url2 numberaverage

url3 numberaverage

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, can you explain further, and an example of the text file you need to parse if posible.

Comment: Have you made an attempt you want help with or are you trying to get started?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i ended up doing it , I wanted to print the dictionary in a column format a 2 by X instead of printing the dictionary in a row

```
    d=dict()
    with open('mathtest.txt') as f:
            while True:
                    url = f.readline().strip()
                    if not url: break
                    average = sum(int(f.readline().strip()) for i in range(3))/3
                    d[url] = average
                    score = str(d[url])
                    print url + " " + score
```

results

URL1 2

URL2 5

URL3 8

URL4 20

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! I just had to alter it a bit to get the results i wanted